# How to change the date time format into other date time format?

Tags: c#

I saw a lot of change date time format, but all change the string to date time and change date time into the string format.

My problem is I failed to convert the date time format (5/1/2020 12:00:00 AM) into date time format (2020/05/01 00:00:00) ***not string***.

My value and text for date time that I saw in Watch

dueDatePicker.Value = {5/1/2020 12:00:00 AM} type is system.DateTime

dueDatePicker.Text = "Friday, May 01, 2020"  type is string

and I tried a lot of methods and I also confuse now. My last method is

```
 DateTime calibrateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(dueDatePicker.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", null);
```

And I get an error:

System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

I need your help to convert the value into date time format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

Comment: Maybe `dueDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")`

Comment: `DateTime` objects don't have a time format. They store only a `long` (number) value of ticks. The only time you see a human-readable date is when the `DateTime` object is written as a string via its `ToString` method, so "not string" is impossible.

Comment: What is the value of `dueDatePicker.Value.GetType()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert a date to a string just to parse it back into a date. Just grab the date directly:

```
DateTime calibrateDate = dueDatePicker.Value;
```

If you want to *display* that date as a string, then convert it using `ToString`:

```
string calibrateDateAsString = calibrateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is how you convert a string to date, but you already have a date type, why are you converting it back to a string and then formatting the string to a date again?

You can just simply do this:

```
dueDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
```